# Get and store a URL segment into a cookie with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

For a kind of conversion tracking, I want to store a part of the URL into a cookie and use this into my model functions.

So I think about `https//:www.example.com?track=this`

How I can get the part of the track `(=this)` with CodeIgniter and save it into a cookie?

To create a cookie I think that's the way,

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
                $cookie = array(
                        'name'   => 'track',
                        'value'  => '???',                            
                        'expire' => '300',                                                                                   
                        'secure' => TRUE
                        );
               set_cookie($cookie);
```

How I can get the part of URL and set cookie etc with CodeIgniter on every possible page? So I mean, no matter over which page the user call the website, I need to make sure that this tracking info is stored in every case.

Go get the cookie later, I think I can use `$cookie= get_cookie('track');`

Thanks for showing me the way to do it with CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the wanted part of the query-string there is a built-in function of Codeigniter

```
$myval=$this->input->get('track', TRUE);
```

I've add this with a part to store and get the cookie in the header of my mainlayout-theme.

So it will works :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Mainly you need to use `parse_url` to extract `url` to `query string` and then `parse_str` to extract `query string`.

First, you need to get `query string` from you `URL`

```
$query = parse_url('https//:www.example.com?track=this&h=1');
echo'<pre>';print_r($query);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [path] => https//:www.example.com
    [query] => track=this&h=1
)
```

> Then you need to extract `query`

```
parse_str($query['query'],$array);
echo'<pre>';print_r($array);die;
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [track] => this
    [h] => 1
)
```

From here you can store your above array information in `cookies`

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for this steps. Could you tell me in wich part / page of the codeigniter project i should integrate it to take care, that this works in every case of possible urls/pages?

Comment: is it worked for you? if yes then please kindly accept the answer, you can put it where you need it, because you didn't give more detail about your requirement so I can't tell more